# How do you count the occurences of a pattern in a list?

Tags: python

Assume I have the following list: `['b(2)','b(6)','a(3)','z(8)',b(4)]` And I want to count how often this list contains b(*), with * being any number. How would I achieve such thing in python?

Comment: Solve the subproblem first: write a function that takes a string argument, and returns `true`/`false` depending on whether string fits the `b(*)` pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
import re
a = ['b(2)','b(6)','a(3)','z(8)','b(4)']
count = sum([1 for i in a if len(re.findall('b\([0-9]\)',i))==1])
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it without using RegEx if the values are always in the above format:

```
# Get the lenght of a list of items in list l if the item (i) contains b
l = ['b(2)','b(6)','a(3)','z(8)','b(4)']    
print(len([i for i in l if "b" in i]))
```

Or

```
import re
l = ['b(2)','b(6)','a(3)','z(8)','b(4)']
# Get the lenght of a list of items in list l if the item (i) matches the regex b\([0-9]\)
print(len([i for i in l if re.search(r'b\([0-9]\)', i)]))
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: This fails when we have elements like `b(1) b(2)` ,i.e two b's in the same element

Comment: @ChayanBansal that's why I put the disclaimer that they must be in the above format e.g. l(x)